# calculating entropy using armadillo library C++

Tags: entropy

I am trying to calculate entropy of a vector using armadillo lib..the code is following. the size of vec is same.whats went wrong..how to fix it.

double ent(){

//arma::vec imT(20);

arma::mat A = randu(4, 5);

arma::vec imT = vectorise(A);  /// vector A is 20 by 1 col vec

double ent; 
    ent = 0;

```
arma::uvec h = hist(imT);   
arma::mat hp = arma::conv_to<arma::mat>::from(imT); 

arma::mat prob = hp/hp.n_elem;

ent = -arma::accu(prob*log2(prob));      //entropy cal
prob.print("sd");
return 0;
```

}

errorr:matrix multiplication: incompaitable matrix dimentions 20x1 and 20X1.

Comment: matrix multiplication is not the same as element-wise multiplication

Comment: Thanks@hbrerkere I got it. It sworking now by using dot product